# Why is my site using index.php instead of archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, archive-template

Developing my first custom theme and I started out using an individual `page-$slug.php` to display a list of each custom post. Have since learned that **archive.php** is better for this purpose (but I just want to use one if possible).

So in admin I've changed the links to the 'post type archive' instead of the page I'd created, and set `has_archive` to true for each cpt.

But the link now takes me to index.php

My archive.php so far is just this:

```
<?php
get_header();

if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()): the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;

get_footer();
?>
```

How do I get it do use the archive.php template and output just the posts of the requested type?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Permalinks are set to 'post type'

Here's the code for 'resource'

```
register_post_type('resource', array(
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies'  => array(
            'category'),
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 
            'editor', 
            'excerpt',
            'page-attributes',
            'custom-fields'),
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Resources',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Resource',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Resource',
            'all_items' => 'All Resources',
            'singular_name' => 'Resource')
    ));
```

and a URL for the archive link is http://youth-cafe.local/resource/

Comment: Are permalinks turned on? What does Query Monitor say in the template hierarchy section? Can you give us an example of a URL and post type?

Comment: Thanks Pratik, however it seems to have started working..... it's suddenly going to archive.php. This may be something to do with Flywheel(?), this has happened previously where changes don't register immediately. I tried rebooting a couple of times but nothing happened until now. I'll add the requested examples anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you're dealing with caching of some sort

Comment: You can disable caching on Flywheel by turning on Development Mode under the Advanced tab.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had same problem,
are you using front-page.php or home.php?

In my case problem was in front-page.php, wp is indexing front-page for homepage and not index.php.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/266598)